# Midrash Tanchuma. Shoftim 12: Colour, or host? What's the explanation?

Tags: midrash, avodah-zarah

> דָּבָר אַחֵר, כִּי הַגּוֹיִם הָאֵלֶּה אֲשֶׁר אַתָּה יוֹרֵשׁ אוֹתָם אֶל מְעֹנֲנִים וְאֶל קֹסְמִים יִשְׁמָעוּ. אָמַר יִרְמְיָה הַנָּבִיא, כִּדְנָה תֵּימְרוּן לְהוֹם וְגוֹ' (ירמיה י, יא). אָמַר רַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר, כִּדְנָא תֵּימְרוּן, אִם יֹאמְרוּ לָכֶם אֻמּוֹת הָעוֹלָם לַעֲבֹד עֲבוֹדָה זָרָה, אִמְרוּ לָהֶם, אִם יְכוֹלָה הִיא לְהַעֲבִיר הַשָּׁמַיִם וְהָאָרֶץ, נַעַבְדֶנָּה. וְאִם לָאו, יֵאבַדוּ מֵאַרְעָא (שם). רַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ אוֹמֵר, אִמְרוֹ לָהֶם, אִם יְכוֹלִין לַעֲשׂוֹת שָׁמַיִם וָאָרֶץ, נַעַבְדֶנָּה. וְאִם לֹא, יֵאבַדוּ מֵאַרְעָא. רַבִּי עֲקִיבָא אוֹמֵר, אִמְרוּ לָהֶם, אִם יְכוֹלִים לְהַעֲבִיר אֶת הַשָּׁמַיִם וְאֶת הָאָרֶץ, וְלַעֲשׂוֹת אֲחֵרִים **מִצֶּבַע אַחֵר**, נַעַבְדֶנָּה. וְאִם לָאו, יֵאבַדוּ מֵאַרְעָא
>
> Another interpretation: "As those nations that you are about to dispossess listen to soothsayers and augurs." Jeremiah the prophet said (Jeremiah 10:11), "Thus shall you say to them, etc." Rabbi Eliezer said, "'Thus shall you say to them': If the nations of the world say to you to worship idolatry, say to them, 'If it is able to remove the heavens and the earth, we will serve it. But if not, "Let it perish from the earth" (Jeremiah 10:11).'" Rabbi Yehoshua said, "Say to them, 'If they are able to make the heavens and the earth, we will serve them, But if not, "Let it perish from the earth".'" Rabbi Akiva said, "Say to them, 'If they are able to remove the heavens and the earth, and to make others from a different **host/colour**, we will serve them, But if not, "Let it perish from the earth".'"

I've seen this translated both ways (although colour is what the word actually means). Either way, what does it all mean? What is this dispute about? Can some idols do one or the other and Rabbi Akiva is being extra strict? What's his strange third condition? Does it mean a different colour or a *new* colour?

Anyone have any sources or connections that discuss any of this? Thank you.

Comment: Presumably whether it’s color or host is a question of the correct Hebrew text - צבע or צבא

Comment: Does it not simply mean that Hashem created everything, He can make people with a different skin-color. As the posuk says, those people were listening to soothsayers. What Rabbi Akiva, according to my own reading, says here is to mean that those soothsayers are nothing, Hashem is the One and the creator of everything. Why worship those soothsayers, can they make people with a different skin-color? Can they make a new heaven and earth? No, so worship G-d.

Comment: @Shmuel I thought it meant the heaven and earth a different colour. Very interesting take thank you

Comment: @JoelK both texts I found had צבע, so I am betting just a translation blunder

Comment: @RabbiKaii You're welcome. I read it as: "If they are able to make others from a different color" etc..., it is not a continuation from the creation of heavens and earth in just a different color.